# Issue with Auto-Responder

Tags: php, html, contact-form, auto-responder

I'm having a little problem while trying to create an auto-respond email for a contact form. The code below is working properly until I try to insert the part with urls. For some reason, when I try to add url links on the message, none of the two emails is sent.. Can you please help me? Thank you very much: (each url posted in the code whould, of course, be a different url)

```
$siteOwnersEmail = 'myemail@domain.com';

$bitter = 'http://example.com/';
$logo = 'http://example.com/img/logo.png';
$dshop = 'https://example.org';
$wchange = 'https://example.net';
$sdrink = 'http://example.com/';
$mclark = 'https://example.com';



if($_POST) {

   $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
   $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
   $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
   $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

   // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
   // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


   // Set Message
   $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
    $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
   $message .= "Message: <br />";
   $message .= $contact_message;
   $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";
    $message2 = 'Hi!,<br /><br />Thanks for contacting us.<br /><br />
    We will respond to your query as soon as possible.<br /><br /><br /><br />
    In the meantime you can find our product available online at <a href="'.$dshop.'"></a>' . $dshop . '
    or <a href="'.$wchange.'"></a>' . $wchange . '
    , Speciality Drinks (<a href="'.$sdrink.'"></a>' . $sdrink . ') 
    and Matthew Clark (<a href="'.$mclark.'"></a>' . $mclark . ') 
    all providing worldwide delivery services.<br /><br />
    From UK and EU you can also order it through this account  for the price of £15 per bottle plus delivery,
    via sending details of quanties needed and a delivery address
    at main@domain.com<br /><br /><br />Kind regards,<br /><br />
    our team<br /><br /><br />
    <a href="'.$bitter.'"></a>' . $bitter . '<br />
<a href="'.$bitter.'"><img src="'.$logo.'" style="width:50px;"></a>';

$subject2 = "Thank you for your message";



   // Set From: header
   $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

   // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers2 = "From: $siteOwnersEmail\r\n";
$headers2 .= "Content-type:  text/html\r\n";


   if (!$error) {

      ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
      $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);    
      $mail = mail($email, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);

        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
      else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

    } # end if - no validation error

    else {

        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

        echo $response;

    } # end if - there was a validation error

}
```

Comment: Are you certain it's not being sent? If it works without URLs and fails with them, it would suggest you're running into a spam filtering issue rather than having an issue with your code.

Comment: I tried checking the spam folder.. no email is in there.. If i stop the $message2 at "We will respond to your query as soon as possible.", both mails are correctly sent.

Comment: As a test, right before you send the email can you addslashes to the body to escape the URL? I have a feeling because it isn’t escaped it may not be working properly, worth testing real quick

Comment: tried with addslashes.. I get the first email, but not the autorespond email